# Applying border to div stops it from page-breaking

Tags: html, css, printing

I found an odd quirk that I can't explain.

I have a template structure like so:

```
<printedpage>
    <div class="print-page">
        <other divs>...
    </div>
<printedpage>

@media print {
    .print-page{
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        break-before: page;
    }

    .print-page:first-child{
        break-before: avoid-page;
        break-after: avoid-page;
        break-inside: avoid!important;
    }
}
```

I have the above css applied to a div. When there is more than one `.print-page`, everything breaks and prints as expected, i.e. one-page per `.print-page` div.

***The problem*** is when there is only one `.print-page`, a second "empty" page is appended to the end of the pdf preview. When I check the emulation mode, I see that there is only one `.print-page` div

***What seems to solve this*** is adding border to the :first-child styling:

```
.print-page:first-child{
    break-before: avoid-page;
    break-after: avoid-page;
    break-inside: avoid !important;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Why does adding a border seemingly fix my issue of breaking to an empty second page?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use `@media` rules for print styles.

```
@media print {
  .print-page:first-child{
    break-before: avoid-page;
    break-after: avoid-page;
    break-inside: avoid !important;
    border: 1px solid white;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying that the css is in fact in a large @media print{ } block.